# При вызове функции go(), выдаёт ошибку: TypeError: go() missing 1 required positional argument: 'root'

Tags: python, ооп, tkinter

```
From tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
import sqlite3

class GOODZONE():

     def __init__(self,root):
     #denote root
     self.root = root

     #create window
     root.title("file")
     root.geometry('100x100')

     self.btn = Button(root,text = "submit", command = self.go)
     self.btn.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

     #cool func
     def go(self, root):
     print("Hello World")

root = Tk()
good = GOODZONE(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Что из текста ошибки не понятно?

Comment: Что непонятно в тексте ошибки?

Comment: Не понятно, как устранить проблему. Впервые с этим столкнулся

Comment: @Krimatotiy Очевидно, не допускать вызова функции `GOODZONE.go` с недостаточным количеством аргументов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Параметр `root` лишний и его можно его просто убрать

```
def go(self):
    print("Hello World")
```

Если в функции `go` вам понадобится `root` то надо будет писать `self.root`

Comment: Его убрать нельзя, тогда запускаться вообще не будет.

Comment: У меня все пашет

Comment: @Krimatotiy будет.

Comment: @Danis Вспомнил гном гномыча ;D

Comment: @VictorVosMottor я его тоже помню, поэтому и написал